# Assertion failure while save document

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, save

I have document based application. It worked fine until I decided to change data model. Now I get error when click on Save or Save As

```
*** Assertion failure in -[NSSavePanel setNameFieldStringValue:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1127.1/Nav.subproj/NSSavePanel.m:1622
Invalid parameter not satisfying: value != nil
```

The strange thing is that error occurs not in my code - I have override method `prepareSavePanel:` in my NSPersistentDocument subclass but program does not reach this point. Error occurs somewhere between `writableTypesForSaveOperation:` and `prepareSavePanel:` (according to [saving steps scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Articles/ObjectInteractions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003196-SW2))

Have you got any ideas?

Comment: What is `writableTypesForSaveOperation:` returning?

Comment: I have not override it, so it returns array with name of the only UTI defined in _Export UTIs_ section in target options.

Comment: You should write your update as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: I know, thank you. I just can't do it right now - only after 8 hours after posting question. So I'll do it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
In my NSPersistentDocument subclass I have override `displayName` method and in some cases it returned `nil` value.
After fixing it all works fine.